# Signal handling

Tags: c, operating-system, signals, fork, exec

I'm currently coding a function that execute external command for an assignment. Here's what I've done, the problem is that the program is taking too long and is interrupted by a SIGALRM.
Thanks for any help!

```
volatile sig_atomic_t sig = 0;

void ext(int signum){
 if(signum==SIGINT || signum==SIGTERM) sig=1;
}

int extern(char **line){
  pid_t p;
  int status;
  struct sigaction as = {0};
  as.sa_handler=ext;
  if (sigaction(SIGINT, &as, 0)==-1||sigaction(SIGTERM, &as, 0)==-1){
    perror("sigaction");
    exit(1);
  }
  switch(p=fork()){
   case -1: perror("fork"); exit(1);
   case 0 : if(execvp(line[0], line)<0) {perror("exec"); exit(1);} break;
   default : //EDIT 
     if(waitpid(p, &status, 0)>=0){
        if (WIFEXITED(status)) return WEXITSTATUS(status);  
      } else {
        perror("wait");
        exit(1);
      }
      break;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does `fork()` return `1` for success, or does it return something else? `case 1:` is unlikely...

Comment: @Fe2O3 it return 0 for the child process and 1 for the parent if I'm not wrong

Comment: @Evelyne In the parent, `fork` returns `-1` on failure, or the PID of the child process on success.

Comment: Thank you, @Oka... Ev, my earlier response was to encourage you to go read and understand the man page for yourself... It's a good idea to develop your independence...

Comment: @Fe2O3 Yes sorry I respond too fast and didn’t recheck ^^’ just edit it thanks!  I copied the code wrongly from my editor haha…

Answer (score 1):

[Signal dispositions](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) are not carried across a call to [`execve`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html). They will be reset as soon as `execvp` executes.

Even if the signal arrives in the child *before* `execpv` executes, the parent and the child process have their own copy of

```
volatile sig_atomic_t sig = 0;
```

The signal handler in the child changing this value would not cause the parent's copy to change.

Establishing a signal handler is not the correct approach to take here.

Instead, your approach of using [`waitpid`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/wait.2.html) is the correct one, but alongside checking for a normal termination of the program with `WIFEXITED(status)`, you should include another branch that checks `WIFSIGNALED(status)`, which will be true if the child process terminated due to a signal.

`WTERMSIG(status)` is used to determine which signal terminated the child process.

Here is a general example where the child process randomly exits successfully, or otherwise [raises](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/raise.3.html) a signal where the default disposition is to terminate the program:

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
    pid_t child = fork();

    if (-1 == child) {
        perror("fork");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    if (0 == child) {
        /* randomly signal or return successfully */
        srand((unsigned) time(NULL));

        switch (rand() % 4) {
            case 1: raise(SIGINT); break;
            case 2: raise(SIGTERM); break;
            case 3: raise(SIGKILL); break;
        }

        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }

    int status;

    if (-1 == waitpid(child, &status, 0)) {
        perror("wait");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    if (WIFSIGNALED(status)) {
        int sig = WTERMSIG(status);

        if (SIGINT == sig || SIGTERM == sig)
            printf("Child <%ld> exited by signal SIGINT or SIGTERM.\n", (long) child);
        else
            printf("Child <%ld> exited by signal #%d.\n", (long) child, sig);
    } else if (WIFEXITED(status)) {
        printf("Child <%ld> exited normally with status %d.\n",
                (long) child,
                WEXITSTATUS(status));
    }
}
```

Output from running this program a few times:

```
Child <41268> exited by signal SIGINT or SIGTERM.
Child <41272> exited by signal SIGINT or SIGTERM.
Child <41276> exited by signal #9.
Child <41280> exited normally with status 0.
```

Comment: Nice! Well beyond my ancient experience with `fork()/exec()` and a pleasure to read... UV'd!!